# Odoo 12 : How to render pdf throught web?

Tags: odoo-12

I'm trying to get pdf from web but when I click the button to render the pdf, I get the error : the file is in text/plain. Here is the code:

```
@http.route('/comande/suivi/<int:orderid>', type='http', auth='user', website=True)
def print_suivi(self, orderid, **kw):
    pdf = request.env.ref('modul_name.report_model_name').report_action(orderid, data={'order': orderid})
    pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf)),
                      ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"')]
    return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)`
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: pdf = request.env.ref('modul_name.report_model_name').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([orderid])[0] fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding `render_qweb_pdf()` you don't need to use `report_action()` method. Try to do something like this :

```
    pdf_report = request.env['report.module_name.report_template_name']
    pdf, _ = request.env.ref('module_name.report_name').sudo().with_context().render_qweb_pdf(pdf_report)
    pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]
    return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```